# Changing activity's background color on phone Orientation

Tags: android

I need to change the background color of the activity when layout is changed from portrait to landscape.

I've already added permissions to manifest and tried changing background color using `setActivityBackgroundColor` from `onCreate`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Log.d("tag", "Portrait");
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         setActivityBackgroundColor(250);
    }
    else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        Log.d("tag", "Landscape");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setActivityBackgroundColor(150);
    }
    else{
        Log.w("tag", "other: " + orientation);
        setActivityBackgroundColor(50);
    }

}
public void setActivityBackgroundColor(int color) {
    View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Comment: If it is working fine, why are you asking a question? Consider reading Stack Overflow's [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Maybe take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your activity tag in manifest.this will allow activity to change configuration on orientation change

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize
```